# Find the minimum line in a list of tuple with repeating values

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

Not happy with the title, but I'm not sure how to make it better.

I have a list of tuples of 3 elements, with repeating values for the first 2 elements. Basically, it represents a kind of matrix (let's say 2 * 3):

```
[(a0, b0, val), (a0, b1, val), (a0, b2, val), (a1, b0, val), (a1, b1, val), (a1, b2, val)]
```

It represents a matrix which looks like:

```
     b0  b1  b2
a0  val val val
a1  val val val
```

For each line, I want to get to the b value corresponding to the lowest val. I'm pretty tired, and what I've come up with is unsatisfying **at best**.

On a specific example, here is what I've done:

```
res = [(915, 1584, 2618.40972202602), (915, 3835, 323.293876052119), (915, 7483, 1521.50879590718), (916, 1584, 2609.47030580952), (916, 3835, 314.354459835623), (916, 7483, 1512.56937969069), (1346, 1584, 3012.63009273444), (1346, 3835, 717.514246760547), (1346, 7483, 1582.83428580677), (4281, 1584, 2603.7125461067), (4281, 3835, 308.596700132804), (4281, 7483, 1464.5140765524), (4282, 1584, 2608.78719959729), (4282, 3835, 313.671353623393), (4282, 7483, 1459.43942306181), (4283, 1584, 2614.00974611433), (4283, 3835, 318.89390014043), (4283, 7483, 1454.21687654477), (4284, 1584, 2619.17131078887), (4284, 3835, 324.05546481497), (4284, 7483, 1449.05531187023), (4287, 1584, 2634.63255731146), (4287, 3835, 339.516711337566), (4287, 7483, 1433.59406534764), (4288, 1584, 2639.73617965108), (4288, 3835, 344.620333677179), (4288, 7483, 1428.49044300803), (4290, 1584, 2650.08066128732), (4290, 3835, 354.96481531342), (4290, 7483, 1418.14596137178), (4297, 1584, 2592.7709526482), (4297, 3835, 297.655106674305), (4297, 7483, 1475.4556700109), (4298, 1584, 2597.94359872049), (4298, 3835, 302.827752746592), (4298, 7483, 1470.28302393861), (4299, 1584, 2603.13534825911), (4299, 3835, 308.019502285211), (4299, 7483, 1465.09127439999), (4305, 1584, 2580.83715850017), (4305, 3835, 285.721312526271), (4305, 7483, 1487.38946415893), (4306, 1584, 2575.62363753943), (4306, 3835, 280.507791565529), (4306, 7483, 1492.60298511968), (4310, 1584, 2555.06067283699), (4310, 3835, 259.94482686309), (4310, 7483, 1513.16594982211), (8350, 1584, 2618.12918933735), (8350, 3835, 323.013343363448), (8350, 7483, 1478.93071978304), (8351, 1584, 2632.5746391363), (8351, 3835, 337.458793162408), (8351, 7483, 1493.376169582)]

r = np.array(res)

c = np.unique(r[:,0])

for val in c:
    d = (val, r[r[:,2]==np.amin(r[r[:,0]==val][:,2])][0,1], r[r[:,2]==np.amin(r[r[:,0]==val][:,2])][0,2])
    print(d)

>>> (915.0, 3835.0, 323.293876052119)
>>> (916.0, 3835.0, 314.354459835623)
>>> (1346.0, 3835.0, 717.514246760547)
>>> (4281.0, 3835.0, 308.596700132804)
>>> (4282.0, 3835.0, 313.671353623393)
>>> (4283.0, 3835.0, 318.89390014043)
>>> (4284.0, 3835.0, 324.05546481497)
>>> (4287.0, 3835.0, 339.516711337566)
>>> (4288.0, 3835.0, 344.620333677179)
>>> (4290.0, 3835.0, 354.96481531342)
>>> (4297.0, 3835.0, 297.655106674305)
>>> (4298.0, 3835.0, 302.827752746592)
>>> (4299.0, 3835.0, 308.019502285211)
>>> (4305.0, 3835.0, 285.721312526271)
>>> (4306.0, 3835.0, 280.507791565529)
>>> (4310.0, 3835.0, 259.94482686309)
>>> (8350.0, 3835.0, 323.013343363448)
>>> (8351.0, 3835.0, 337.458793162408)
```

This can then be put back into another "minimum lines only" numpy array. Note that it happens, in this specific case, to point towards the same b-value for every line, this is by "chance" and should not be assumed.

While this technically works, I must say I've rarely seen uglier code. I am positive there has to be a much smarter and clearer way of doing what I want to get at. Any suggestions?

Note also that I can know how many "repeat" there is (that is, the size of the b set) beforehand, if that's absolutely needed.

Comment: your problem is classified as data  manipulation/munging. Numpy is not a good tool to handle this issue. You are better using `pandas`.

Comment: Damn, didn't think of this, thanks! It seems to work very well, I'll post the better answer once I get this going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=res, columns=['0', '1', '2'])
print(df.loc[df.groupby('0')['2'].idxmin()])
```

result:

```
       0     1           2
1    915  3835  323.293876
4    916  3835  314.354460
7   1346  3835  717.514247
10  4281  3835  308.596700
13  4282  3835  313.671354
16  4283  3835  318.893900
19  4284  3835  324.055465
22  4287  3835  339.516711
25  4288  3835  344.620334
28  4290  3835  354.964815
31  4297  3835  297.655107
34  4298  3835  302.827753
37  4299  3835  308.019502
40  4305  3835  285.721313
43  4306  3835  280.507792
46  4310  3835  259.944827
49  8350  3835  323.013343
52  8351  3835  337.458793
```

Comment: Yep, that's it. I had not thought of using pandas, thanks!